# Does the BTU change on different fan speeds?

Tags: air-conditioning

I can only find a 14,000 btu window a/c for my small room.  I really only need an 8,000 or 10,000 btu but can’t get one in my area.  I was just wondering if I kept a/c on lowest speed, would the btu be less??  Thanks!

Comment: I think the BTUs deal with the compressor/cooling system, while the fan only deals with air movement, so the fan speed will not change the BTUs, but will change how fast the room cools.

Answer (score 2):

The air conditioner has a thermostat, so hardly ever uses its *maximum* BTU cooling capacity. Being oversized just means it will cycle off more often, but the room will still be at the temperature you set.

However, an oversized air conditioner has a few possible disadvantages:

- It would be a bit [less effective at removing *humidity* from the air](https://www.cooltoday.com/blog/3-problems-caused-by-an-oversized-air-conditioner).
- It draws more current when cycling on. Electric bills *won't* be appreciably higher, because the compressor would not run as long as that in a small unit, but the wiring must be able to handle the higher current.
- It likely would cost a bit more than a smaller unit.

That said, a unit 50% larger than ideal likely would *not* be a major issue.

Comment: note that an inverter AC will run at lower BTUs when required, this advice is good for non-inverting ones though, which is more of the older ones and cheaper newer ones.